# asp.net javascript: get innertext of treeview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have a treeview on a web forms application.

i have javascript function that gets called every time there is a click inside the treeview:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              function OnTreeClick(evt) {
                  var src = window.event != window.undefined ? window.event.srcElement : evt.target;
                  var nodeClick = src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a";
                  if (nodeClick) {
                      var nodeText = src.innerText;
                      var nodeValue = GetNodeValue(src);
                      alert("Text: " + nodeText + "," + "Value: " + nodeValue);
                  }
                  //return false; //uncomment this if you do not want postback on node click
              }
              function GetNodeValue(node) {
                  //node value
                  var nodeValue = "";
                  var nodePath = node.href.substring(node.href.indexOf(",") + 2, node.href.length - 2);
                  var nodeValues = nodePath.split("\\");
                  if (nodeValues.length > 1)
                      nodeValue = nodeValues[nodeValues.length - 1];
                  else
                      nodeValue = nodeValues[0].substr(1); return nodeValue;
              }
</script>
```

**question**: how do i catch whether a user clicked on a checkbox inside the tree view? and how do i retrieve the text next to it?

here is the markup of the treeview:

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowLines="True" 
        onselectednodechanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" 
        ontreenodecheckchanged="TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged" CssClass="mytreeview"
        >
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="PreAnalytical" Value="PreAnalytical">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Labels" Value="Labels">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Specimen collection device mislabeled/unlabeled by practice" 
                        Value="Specimen collection device mislabeled/unlabeled by practice" 
                        ShowCheckBox="True">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Specimen mislabeled: in-house error (Lab or DE)" 
                        Value="Specimen mislabeled: in-house error (Lab or DE)" 
                        ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Test Requisitions" Value="Test Requisitions">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Missing: no form sent with specimen" 
                        Value="Missing: no form sent with specimen" ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Wrong (i.e. OT instead of ORAL, sister practice)" 
                        Value="Wrong (i.e. OT instead of ORAL, sister practice)" 
                        ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Other: Non-ML" Value="Other: Non-ML" ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Copies Received: New ID/Req. assigned" 
                        Value="Copies Received: New ID/Req. assigned" ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Incomplete/Blank Requisition Form" 
                        Value="Incomplete/Blank Requisition Form" ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="2 Specimens: 1 Req" Value="2 Specimens: 1 Req" 
                        ShowCheckBox="True">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="2 Reqs: 1 Specimen" Value="2 Reqs: 1 Specimen" 
                        ShowCheckBox="True">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Validity" Value="Need POC Results Confirmed">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Need POC Results Confirmed" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="POC Results Marked Incorrectly" Value="New Node">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="No Tests Ordered" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="SEC A Unclear" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Sales" Value="Sales">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Practice is not entered in database" Value="New Node">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="CP has not been updated" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Other" Value="Other">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Other" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Analytical" Value="Analytical"></asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Post-Analytical" Value="Post-Analytical"></asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function check_OnTreeNodeChecked(event)
{
    var TreeNode = event.srcElement || event.target ;
    if (TreeNode.tagName == "INPUT" && TreeNode.type == "checkbox")
    {
        if(TreeNode.checked)
        {
            //Do whatever here
        }
    }
}
```

Then attach this function with treeview onclick event:

```
private void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeView1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "check_OnTreeNodeChecked(event)");
}
```

Comment: how would i get the text of the treenode?

Comment: thanks so much for your help. i am doing this: function check_OnTreeNodeChecked(event) {
                  var TreeNode = event.srcElement || event.target;
                  if (TreeNode.tagName == "INPUT" && TreeNode.type == "checkbox") {
                      if (TreeNode.checked) {
                          alert(TreeNode.innerHTML);
                      }
                  }
              }   and getting a blank string returned

Comment: Can you post the result of alert(TreeNode.outerHTML)?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="TreeView1n7CheckBox" name="TreeView1n7CheckBox">